# Eclipse Platform Version: 3.7.2 doesn't allow anonymous unions

Tags: c++, eclipse, g++

here is a snippet from my project ->

```
union {
    struct {
        double x;
        double y;
        double z;
    };
    struct {
        double r;
        double g;
        double b;
    };
};
```

from command line g++ is able to compile this, but eclipse IDE says

```
Description    Resource Path    Location    Type
invalid use of non-static data member ‘Vector3d::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::C/C++ Problem
```

I know some similar problems are discussed before. BUt in my case, I am just curious why IDE which uses the very same compiler namely g++ won't compile and how I can get it to work?

thanks in advance

Comment: G++ might compile a similar example, but it *doesn't* compile this.

Comment: @OlafDietsche http://ideone.com/AWskSj

Comment: As I said, a similar example. You should show your complete source code. Nobody can guess from such an incomplete snippet.

Comment: @OlafDietsche lol, maybe that's true, maybe it has to do with my complete source code. However, what did 'this' refer to in your comment -> "G++ might compile a similar example, but it doesn't compile *this*"

Comment: With *this*, I meant the example snippet you've shown above. I just copied it to a file and it doesn't compile with g++ (4.6.3).

Comment: g++(4.6.3) perfectly compiles it on my system(ubuntu 12.04)